# Client to Server Authentication in C++ using sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, authentication, encryption

I'm implementing a login/authentication system for my little server-client program. I'm wondering how to go about this, and I was hoping to get some great tips/advice from Stack Overflow as always. This is how I imagine I'll do it.

- Client  connects to the server.
- Server sends a 'token' to the Client (based on time probably and whatever)
- Client returns the username and a sha1 encrypted password, along with the token.
- Server receives them and authenticates the user to the credentials in the server-side database.
- The token is now verified and the user is signed in with the token.

Is this at all a secure way of doing it? I figured the client also sends a serial key or some such to form a serial / token pair, so that another client cannot fake the same token (though the token is generated by the server-side).

Implementation details aren't required, as I am capable of doing the implementation.

My question would, rather, two questions:

- What ways are there to achieve a login/authentication system with sockets
- What ways are there to secure my client-to-server connection
- **EDIT**: I forgot to ask, as this is a C++ question, are there any libraries that can assist in encryption/authentication?

Security is an issue for me, so I want to be sure I do it right.

Maybe some background information. It's a game server, a person logs in with his account and is taken to a 'Lobby', where he can pick a 'World Server' to play on. The world server is a separate process running (possibly) on a different machine in the same network.

For that reason, I want to have a concept of a session in this, the user logs in and a session is generated, the login server relays the session to the world server the user picks, so that world server knows that the user is actually logged in.

I reckon the client will have to confirm the session to the world server and all that, but I'll worry about that later.

Sincerely,
*Jesse*

Comment: By the way, great question. Clear, specific, well written, correct grammer, etc. +1!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You generally do *not* want to send the password over the link at all, not even with encryption. The usual method is a challenge-response protocol.

1. The client connects to the server, sending in the user-name (but *not* password)
2. The server responds by sending out unique random number
3. The client encrypts that random number using the hash of their password as the key
4. The client sends the encrypted random number to the server
5. The server encrypts the random number with the correct hash of the user's password
6. The server compares the two encrypted random numbers

This has a couple of advantages. First, it means the password never goes over the link in any form. Second, it's immune to a replay attack -- if an attacker records the conversation, they can't replay the client's replies later to log in, because the random number will have changed.

Securing the connection (i.e., encrypting the content) is a little simpler. Typically, one of the two (doesn't really matter much which) picks a random number, encrypts it with the other's public key, and sends it to the other. The other decrypts it, and they encrypt the rest of the session using that as a key for symmetric encryption.

Libraries: [Beecrypt](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/doxygen/c++/index.html) and [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) are a couple of obvious ones. Unless you have a fairly specific reason to do otherwise, TLS is what you probably want to use (it does quite a bit more than what I've outlined above, including two-way authentication, so not only does the server know who the client is, but the client also knows who the server is, so it's reasonably verified that it's not connected to somebody else who might just collect his credit card number and run with it).

Edit:

To authenticate each packet without the overhead of encrypting everything, you could do something like this:

1. The server sends its public key with the challenge
2. The client generates a random number, encrypts it with the server's public key, and sends it back with its response
3. The number is the first number used for counter-mode encryption
4. The client includes one counter-mode result with each packet it sends

Counter mode means you just generate consecutive numbers, and encrypt each in turn, using the right key. In this case, the key would be the hash of the client's password. What this means is that each packet will contain a unique random number that both the client and the server can generate, but nobody else can. By using the counter-mode encryption, each packet will have a unique random number. By starting from a random number, each session will have a unique sequence of random numbers.

To minimize overhead, you could send just a part of the result with each packet -- e.g., if you use AES in counter mode, it'll generate 16 bytes of result for each number you encrypt. Include only (say) two bytes of that with each packet, so you only have to encrypt a number once every 8 packets. In theory, this cuts security -- an attacker could just try all 65536 possible values for a packet, but if you assume the connection has been compromised after (say) two bad attempts, the chances of an attacker getting the right value become pretty small (and, of course, you can pretty much pick the chances you're willing to live with by controlling the number of bad attempts you allow and the size of authentication you include in each packet).

Comment: Great answer, that was kind of what I was hoping for. Do I have to worry about authentication after these steps? Or can I assume that for the rest of the connection that it's okay.

Comment: @JesseBrands: It depends on how security conscious you're being. If you really care, you can have the server send its public key along with the challenge, and the client send back a session key (encrypted with the public key) with its response, then use encryption for the rest of the session.

Comment: ps: Credit Card data is not a concern. Aside from logging in to the server, no sensitive data is ever sent from the client or from the server. From there on it's just packets with requests from the client to the server, and responses from the server. (i.e.: User requests to attack enemyX, server does a dice roll etc and responds with the damage done, also checks if the user can actually attack etc). In that sense, speed is an issue, which is why I don't want to "oversecure" the connection.

Comment: @JesseBrands: I've added a bit about one way to have per-packet authentication with fairly minimal overhead.

Comment: Sounds a bit unnecessary. Regardless, your answer is very detailed and gave me a lot of insight on the matter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you once more, I implemented the challenge-response technique you listed and it works great. :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin The point "The client encrypts that random number using the hash of their password as the key" implies that client has access to its password. Which in turn implies that client has saved its password with itself. Lets say a user of the client owns only one password. Doesn't this mean that one client can be used to connect only one user in all its life? Also as the number of passwords increase at server, it will have to send those passwords to the client so that other users of the client can use those passwords to connect with server.

Comment: @Waseem: Typically, the client will ask the user to enter their user name and password at run time. After initial entry, they might use some sort of secure storage on/connected to the client, such as a smart card or OS-provided secure storage (e.g., OS X key chain).

Answer (score 0):

If security is a big issue for you, don't roll your own. You want a secure socket library. Something like [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Comment: Well, I don't think the socket itself would need securing, other than a password, no sensitive data is ever sent. I think OpenSSL might be to heavyweight for what I intend to do. Actually thinking of it, the authentication server is it's own process, so I might just use OpenSSL purely for that part.

Comment: @JesseBrands: it all depends on how much security your really need.